# Is there a C++ allocator that prevent an STL container from being swapped?

Tags: c++, stl, memory-management, posix, allocator

Has anyone seen an allocator that calls [mlock(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock) to prevent an STL container's contents from being swapped to disk?

There is afaik only one tricky part to writing such an allocator, namely minimizing the number of mlocked pages by clustering allocations to be mlocked.  Ergo, one should probably start by modifying some shared memory allocator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*If* I wanted to implement this (which is difficult to imagine, because I find it hard to believe it's the right solution to any problem :^), I'd try to do it by using a [`boost::pool_allocator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/pool_alloc.html) (which provides a standard library compatible Allocator from a pool) and then - I forget the details; think it'll involve the `RequestedSize` template argument to [`singleton_pool`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/singleton_pool.html) and a [`user_allocator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/pool/doc/interfaces/user_allocator.html) ? - there will be some way of having that sit on top of a pool which requests bigger chunks of memory by the mechanism of your choice which in your case would be allocation of mlocked pages.

Comment: +1 for "I find it hard to believe it's the right solution to any problem"

Comment: @BillyONeal: locked pages can be good for security information and also good for programs that need to be instantly responsive to the user, although in that case mlockall is a better choice.

Comment: Yes, you would need this if writing a cryptographic library/tools from scratch in C++ for example.  Yes, obviously you should use established libraries for cryptography whenever possible.

Comment: @ZanLynx: Maybe for the crypto case, but not for the responsiveness case. Who is your program to be the one that says "I'm the most important, listen to me! Make other programs run slower so that I look better" -- if your program is getting paged that means the user is using other programs, making those programs pages more important than yours. If you're doing this for responsiveness, you are changing global state to fix a local problem.

Comment: There might by industrial data collection applications where mlockall was appropriate for a small demon, but the real time stuff was overkill, no?